# how to implement the swap function when the object type is not known

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement all the `STL` functions on my own.

In the `make_heap` function i need to swap the two objects. Now since i want it to `STL` like i cannot change my argument list.

**So i cannot declare a variable of the `object` that the `first` is pointing to.**

I also cannot use the `swap without temporary variables`

```
swap (RandomAccessIterator a,RandomAccessIterator b)
{
    *a = *a + *b;
    *b = *a - *b;
    *a = *a - *b;
}
```

because the operators `+` and `-` may not be overloaded for the given object the two pointers are pointing to.

Here is my Code :

```
template <class RandomAccessIterator>

void make_heap (RandomAccessIterator first,RandomAccessIterator last)
{

    int num_ele = (last - first) + 1;
    for (int i=num_ele-1;i>=1;i--)
    {
        if (first[i] < first[(i-1)/2])
        {
            swap (/* Here is where i am struck..! */);
        }
    }


}
```

PS : Assume the `objects` are comparable under < operator.

Comment: Use temporary variable instead of + - hack.

Comment: yea..that would be possible if when what the type of the variable is beforehand which i dont here

Comment: `auto` or `iterator_trait`.

Comment: i dont know what they are...can u please give me links to where i can find more about these...?

Comment: There's a little trick for swapping two numeric variables, without using a temporary variable: `a=a+b; b=a-b; a=a-b;` If the + and - operators are commutative,associative,invertible and have an identity, like the mathematical + and -, then you can use this trick.
But still this is just a hack, not a clean solution.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/iterator_traits/ or http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use something like (in C++11):

```
void iter_swap(RandomAccessIterator a, RandomAccessIterator b)
{
    auto temp(std::move(*a));
    *a = std::move(*b);
    *b = std::move(temp);
}
```

or using `std::iterator_traits`

```
void iter_swap(RandomAccessIterator a, RandomAccessIterator b)
{
    std::iterator_traits<RandomAccessIterator>::value_type temp(std::move(*a));
    *a = std::move(*b);
    *b = std::move(temp);
}
```

Comment: In C++11, `auto` is a keyword to auto-deduce the type. `iterator_traits` uses specialization to handle the different case.

Comment: how did they implement this before C++11 came into existence...?? is it by @6502 's method given below...?

Comment: @PRP: yes, before C++11, `swap` did a copy.

Comment: You probably want to use ADL found `swap` as it will be much more efficient with different types.

Answer (score 1):

You should not try to swap the values that were given to you, but rather let the library and the user provide the correct way of swapping values for the type you are interested in:

```
using std::swap;
swap(a,b);
```

The implementation makes use of a using-declaration to bring `std::swap` into scope and then uses an unqualified call to `swap` that will find the `std::swap` generic function and possibly a user provided ADL found function.  If there is such a function, it will be preferred over the standard one.

Short story: you should *not* be concerned with how to swap the values, the library knows, and the user has an extension point if they want to tweak the behavior for a particular type beyond what the standard `swap` does. That extension point is ADL found `swap`.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `swap` as a template function

```
template<typename T>
void swap(T& a, T& b) {
    T c(a); a = b; b = c;
}
```

and the call it from your code as:

```
swap(*a, *b);
```

Also this way the user can define a template specialization for swapping.

Comment: This makes unnecessary copies. Just try it with a large vector, and compare it to Jarod42's answer which moves instead of copying.

Comment: @hvd: you can specify custom swapping by defining a template specialization.

Comment: @6502 Yes, but firstly, you'd then be stuck re-implementing it for every type where copies are expensive, and secondly, there are no function template partial specialisations, so you cannot provide any specialisation for `vector<T>`, only separate specialisations for `vector<int>`, `vector<long>`, `vector<void *>`, `vector<string>`, etc.

Answer (score -2):

Can't you use XOR swap algorithm here? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm

Comment: actually i had done that also..that would require byte by byte reading and then xoring both and would be a dirty solution.